# What exactly is being done by Salesforce in Summer 15 update to HTML Area home page components?

Tags: visualforce, home-page-component, summer-15, html-area-component

I'm trying to understand what and how exactly we gonna get effected with this change.

As per this help link - [Changes to Home Page Components](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Home-Page-Components-Changes-Starting-Summer-14&), it does answer almost all but I'm not entirely clear of the fact about what is going to happen to existing components.

Considering we already have a package in motion with 100s of installs. And below is the code being used:

```
<iframe src="/apex/nmspace__MyLoginMessage?mp=1" frameborder="0" height="100%" scrolling="auto" width="100%"></iframe>
```

So, with Summer '15:

1. Will this Home Page component does not load at all?... `OR`
2. The component will still load and work properly. But we'll not be able to Modify it, since when we Edit and Save then the IFRAME tag will get auto removed on Save?
3. Considering the existing component does not interact using JavaScript with components outside of the container iFrame as it is just an iFrame showing VF page, will Salesforce in Summer 15 update force Remove all iFrame tags or Script tags in the Home Page Components (without we as developer updating anything in the component)?

In summary, a quick answer I seek is for someone confirming me if we leave the Home Page Components which have iFrame tags only, will continue working unless we actually have to go in and Edit the components? Or will they break down no matter if we edit it or not, they will just stop working or loading iFrame hosted page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iframe will be removed entirely from the component's source. This will effectively cause the component to not render its contents anymore. You must convert to a Visualforce component, which means you'll also have to tell your customers to upgrade before the release, or they will lose this functionality.

Comment: Thats sad...  Since ideally i want to replace components with same title and name and that means when users are editing Home Page Layouts they will see 2 components with same name.  :-( ... Any suggestions to tackle this situation? @sfdcfox...

Comment: @VarunC I'm pretty sure you, as the ISV package provider, could update the component. Alternatively, you could delete the component and then provide a new one with a slightly different label. It's been a while since I've had to mess with managed packages, though, so you might want to contact partner support.

Comment: I've marked this as answer as it was that much closer to what I could confirm from Summer 15 Pre-release org. Salesforce has removed the iFrame and actually they removed HTML tags all together in short.